# pdfbox extract word coordinates

Tags: coordinates, extract, pdfbox, cpu-word

Hi This question refers to previous post:

[Could someone give me an example of how to extract coordinates for a 'word' using PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330484/could-someone-give-me-an-example-of-how-to-extract-coordinates-for-a-word-usin)

I am using PDFBOX 2.0.10

I have successfully compiled the combined code but getting exception error when trying to run an example.

The solution provided does not have a standard main method which is where I am getting confused.

Can someone please advise how I can run the combined code successfully.

```
package org.apache.pdfbox.examples.text;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.pdfbox.examples.text.ExtractWordCoordinates;
public class ExtractWordCoordinates2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ExtractWordCoordinates ewc = new ExtractWordCoordinates();
       ewc.testExtractWordsForGoodJuJu();
    }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
Jul 08, 2018 4:15:41 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB suggestKCMS
INFO: To get higher rendering speed on java 8 oder 9,
Jul 08, 2018 4:15:41 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB suggestKCMS
INFO:   use the option -Dsun.java2d.cmm=sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider
Jul 08, 2018 4:15:41 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB suggestKCMS
INFO:   or call System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider")
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFile.createBuffer(ScratchFile.java:422)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1142)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1041)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.text.ExtractWordCoordinates.testExtractWordsForGoodJuJu(ExtractWordCoordinates.java:47)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.text.ExtractWordCoordinates2.main(ExtractWordCoordinates2.java:17)
```

ExtractWordCoordinates can be found here
https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractWordCoordinates.java#L69

Comment: *"getting exception error"* - which exception? Please include stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The following line in ExtractWordCoordinates was returning a null:

```
    try (   InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("apache.pdf")) {
```

After copying the document (apache.pdf) to the same directory as ExtractWordCoordinates.class the code ran successfully.